Is it possible to have intersection of L1 and L2 DFA contain states with no input edge?
I am doing a HW problem where I have L1 and L2.
I did the product construction method to produce all the new states of the DFA representing L1 and L2 (the number of states in L1 times the number of states in L2 is the new amount of states in the DFA that accepts L1 and L2).
Then, I  added in all the incoming and outcoming edges from a table that I made.
But I notice there are states that do not have incoming edges.
Does this imply that I have an error in my procedure or is this a valid outcome.
TAs don't know the answer, so I would appreciate some insight. Prof doesn't give answers either. My text book is:  Intro to computer theory (cohen)

Yes, this is totally possible.
The product-construction you use has an edge $((p,p'),a,(q,q'))$ if the original automata have edges $(p,a,q)$ and $(p',a,q')$.
In the picture below I have an example of the product construction, where I have omitted the states that cannot be reached from the initial state. That means there is no path to such a state. A clear missing example is state $(2,q)$. The reason is simple. In the first automaton $2$ has only incoming edges with label $a$. In the second automaton $q$ has only an incoming edge with label $b$. Thus there is no label possible into $(2,q)$ that combines both automata.
My construction is "on the fly". I have started with the initial state $(1,p)$ and have only added states when they appeared dusring the construction. In that way we obtain only reachable states.
The product automaton is for the language "contains a substring ab or bba".

(click & remove the final m to obtain a larger figure)

Thank you very much for the thorough reply, I really appreciate it.
I assume this reasoning applies for outgoing edges as well. My new FA produced some 'garbage' states with no possible outgoing edges, (so transitions exist for a specific input in either L1 or L2).

For outgoing edges this depends on the "type" of the initial automata. If they are deterministic every state has a unique outgoing edge with label $a$ and so does the product. (As in my example.) Starting with nondeterministic automata, if $p$ and $q$ in the two automata do not have outgoing label in common, then the product has no outgoing edge for combined state $(p,q)$.
